# NodeJS: make a call on session cleanup (maxAge)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session, express-session

Is it possible to execute a function before the session will be destroyed in Express-session middleware?

Comment: yes. It's possible

Comment: is there a particular method for that?

Comment: No, you have to implement and manage it yourself